# Show background image on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show an background image with some text inside when im hoovering the navigation link, but for some reason the image wont show up.

Here some of the title css

```
   .navigation h1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 22px;
    top: -7px;
    display: none;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 7px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/dbnCNPk.png') 100% 50% no-repeat;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>one</h1>
            <a href="#hem" class="active">one</a>                      </li>
        <li>    <h1>two</h1>
            <a href="#two">two</a></li>
        <li>    <h1>three</h1>
            <a href="#three">three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And a Fiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBsDp/2/)

Comment: What is the desired result? The H1 is set to `display:none;`

Comment: Of course damn , updated now

Comment: Try avoiding multiple h1's per page! Use h2 or h3 instead. https://www.google.com/#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+many+h1+per+page&oq=how+many+h1&gs_l=hp.3.0.35i39j0l3.1996.3713.0.4905.11.11.0.0.0.0.106.899.9j2.11.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.IGm3D-5p5BU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49405654%2Cd.d2k%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.QXiTEk6XjhM.O&fp=e4bf48cf8eb7c60f&biw=1920&bih=955

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/VBsDp/1/

Check out the fiddle.

You didn't have a hover class to show the h1.  I added:

```
.navigation li:hover h1 {
    display:block;
}
```

I have actually updated it again:

http://jsfiddle.net/VBsDp/3/

This time I added:

```
top: -35px;
```

for the `h1` and put

```
positon: relative;
```

for the `li`

Comment: I added another modification for the positioning of the h1 so it's aligned with the bullet.

Comment: i was just wondering that. This work lika a charm now. Thank you so much friend.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the display of the h1 on hover

```
.navigation:hover h1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This will show all h1 elements at the same time.  The code I put has the hover on the li to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navigation h1 {
position: absolute;
right: 22px;
top: -7px;
display: none;  /*  <-- were you expecting some magic ? */
...
}
```

Your css makeover seems a little messed up. You only 'hover' declaration is :

```
.navigation a:hover{
border-radius:25px;
background-color:#f68A33;
}
```

witch will NOT achieve what you want. It just manage the A tag.

So, if you want some action to happen on the  tag, you will have to scope it.

```
h1 { remove the display:none; h1 is block-level by default}
h1.hover {do your background thing here }
```

Comment: I thought the same thing at first and then realised he wanted to add the hover attribute :)

Answer (score 1):

you can user hover in css as :

```
   .navigation h1:hover {
    background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/dbnCNPk.png') 100% 50% no-repeat;
    }
```

and adjust the position.

Comment: The h1 tag is in display: none; though so hovering isn't possible.  Check out the answer I posted.

Comment: I'm kind of .. not sure .. but, are we actually teaching some very very very basic .css ? :hover ? What the heck is :hover ? Never herd of :hover. By the way, it won't apply since H1 is display:none. ;)